# Why don't I get an segmentation fault when I overflow a vector with my custom allocator?

Tags: c++, c++11

I've written a custom LinearAllocator that I'm using with a vector. The Allocator can take another Allocator as a template/constructor parameter to allocate its initial storage from. Right now it's making it's initial allocation with the std::allocator just fine, but when I overflow the vector it doesn't give an error. I understand this is undefined behavior so I can't guarantee a segfault, but it consistently allows me to modify 1037600 elements from the beginning of the vector (of size 64).

I printed out and modified each element until it gave me an error:

```cpp
template <class T, size_t N, class Alloc = std::allocator<uint8_t>>
class LinearAllocator
{
public:
    typedef T value_type;

    LinearAllocator()
    :m_memory{m_alloc.allocate(N)}, m_head{m_memory}
    {
    }

    template<class U>
    LinearAllocator(LinearAllocator<U, N> const& other) noexcept
    :m_memory{other.m_memory}, m_head{other.m_head}
    {}

    template<class U>
    bool operator==(LinearAllocator<U, N> const& other) const noexcept
    {
        return m_memory == other.m_memory && m_head == other.m_head;
    }

    template<class U>
    bool operator!=(LinearAllocator<U, N> const& other) const noexcept
    {
        return !(*this == other);
    }

    T* allocate(const size_t n)
    {
        uint8_t* memory = static_cast<uint8_t*>(m_memory);
        uint8_t* head = static_cast<uint8_t*>(m_head);

        if(n == 0)
        {
            return nullptr;
        }

        if(n > static_cast<size_t>(-1) / sizeof(T))
        {
            throw std::bad_array_new_length();
        }

        if(n > N) { throw std::bad_alloc(); }

        if(memory + N < head + n) { head = memory; }

        void* pv = m_head;
        head += n;
        m_head = static_cast<void*>(head);

        return static_cast<T*>(pv);
    }

    void deallocate(T* const p, size_t) const noexcept
    {}

private:
    Alloc m_alloc = Alloc();
    void* m_memory = nullptr;
    void* m_head = nullptr;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<uint8_t, LinearAllocator<uint8_t, 64>> vec(64, 1);
    //std::vector<uint8_t> vec(65, 1);

    std::cout << (void*)vec.data() << std::endl;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < vec.size()+10000000; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << i << " " << (int)vec[i]++ << " " << (int)vec[i]<< "\n";
    }
}
```

I expected this to fail upon overflow at element 64, since I thought this was heap allocated memory. But it seems to fail at the same point, element 1037663, way past where I expected.
Specifically:

$ ./run

0 1 2

1 1 2

...

1037662 0 1

1037663 0 1

Segmentation fault: 11

Comment: Undefined behaviour is *undefined*, not "defined as segmentation fault". You cannot expect any particular manifestation of failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely cause is that when you allocated space from `std::allocator`, it grabbed enough memory from the OS to hold 1037663 elements.  The segmentation fault occurs when the OS notices that you've asked to look at a memory address that it hasn't already given your program permission to access.  The `std::allocator` has asked for the other memory from the OS and so the OS will not notice when you exceed the bounds of the `vector` until you go beyond the bounds of memory provided to the `std::allocator`.